# Correct names, but "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type"

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm stuck with this error:

```
cities.c: In function ‘main’:
cities.c:7:48: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct Graph’
  printf("well, it got here. nodeCount: %d\n", x->nodeCount);
```

All other solutions point out that names are misspelled and thus undefined, however, if I move the `struct Graph` definition to the header, it works just fine.

I had previously used this mechanic in my other library and it still compiles just fine, I've spent hours trying to move things around to no avail.

graph.h:

```
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H

typedef struct Graph * Graph;

int graphCreate(Graph*, int);
int graphAddPath(Graph, int, int, unsigned int);
int graphRemovePath(Graph, int, int);
int graphDestroy(Graph*);

#endif /* GRAPH_H */
```

graph.c: https://pastebin.com/FzkaJJwP

cities.c:

```
#include "graph.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    Graph x;
    graphCreate(&x, 5);
    printf("well, it got here. nodeCount: %d\n", x->nodeCount);
}
```

Output is as expected in my library at https://git.mif.vu.lt/emiliskiskis/c_deck.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: `typedef struct Graph * Graph;` this is very misleading, I recommend renaming it something more descriptive like `GraphPtr`. Because people look at `Graph x;` and think that there's a `Graph` on the stack, when it really is just a pointer.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: You can't access fields of incomplete structs, an `struct Graph` is incomplete here.

Comment: How should the compiler know about member `nodeCount` if you hide the struct definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The definition of the `struct Graph` is in the `graph.c` file. When you compile the `cities.c` file this definition is not visible.  You need to move the definition to `graph.h`

   ```
   struct Graph {
      unsigned int **matrix;
      int nodeCount;
   };
   ```
2. As suggested by Blaze, the below definition is confusing. `typedef struct Graph * Graph`. A better solution would be to

   ```
   typedef struct Graph Graph;
   ```

and then in the code you can use

```
int graphCreate(Graph **, int);
int graphAddPath(Graph *, int, int, unsigned int);
int graphRemovePath(Graph *, int, int);
int graphDestroy(Graph **);
```

Comment: Hi, this was my personal library (not to share), so I just know what's going on, but thanks for the suggestion. I wrote a function to return the node count and it works. Thank you very much, as well to @HolyBlackCat and @Gerhardh!

Answer (score 0):

The compiler message is pretty clear. The type is incomplete, which basically means that the compiler only knows that it exists a struct named Graph, but it does not know what it looks like. The consequence of this is that you cannot access the fields.

So, first you have to answer this question. Do you want the programmer that is using the library to be able to access the fields of Graph? If no, put the definition in the .c file. If yes, put the definition in the .h file.

One more thing to consider is `typedef struct Graph * Graph`. You're hiding an awful lot of information when typedefing a struct, and the same goes for when you are typedefing a pointer. Now you're doing both. My personal opinion is that you really should avoid doing this, unless the answer to the above question is "no".

My suggestion is, if you want the user of the library to be able to access the fields of struct Graph, remove the typedef completely. If you want to hide it from the user, code access functions, like this:

```
// cities.h
int getNodeCount(Graph g);
```

```
// cities.c
int getNodeCount(struct Graph * g) {
    return g->nodeCount;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
Graph g;
int nodeCount = getNodeCount(g);
```

Do note that i did NOT use the typedef in the function definition. Only in it's prototype.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since I wrote this library for myself, I just know what this will look like, but thanks for the suggestions.